# callback function when scrolling in 1 direction

Tags: jquery

How can I get a callback when I scroll to the right 300px?

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="scrollable">
        this will be 6000px wide
    </div>

</div>
```

css

```
#container {width: 900px; overflow: hidden;}
.scrollable {width: 6000px; overflow-x: scroll;}
```

js  (feel free to re-write, I just tried this as example)

```
$('#container').scroll(function (evt) {
    var target = $(evt.currentTarget);
    horizontal_scroll = target.scrollLeft();
    if (previous_scroll < horizontal_scroll && horizontal_scroll % 100 == 0) {
        previous_scroll = horizontal_scroll;
        alert("You've scrolled 300px to the right");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [$.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method to determine how far the inner `div` has moved and fire an alert once it goes beyond -300px (negative) like this:

```
var alerted = false; // prevents unlimited alerts
$('#container').on('scroll', function(e){
    var el = $(this),
        os = $('.scrollable',this).offset();

    if (os.left <= -300 && alerted !== true){
        alert('Scrolled 300px');
        alerted = true; // prevent unlimited alerts
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4upYj/

I hope this helps!